# How to use 'glossaries' package in aquamacs, or I mean how could I run makeglossaries in aquatics

Tags: aquamacs

I find the instruction from [enter link description here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Glossaries) as given below

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\title{How to create a glossary}
\author{ }
\date{ }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. 

\clearpage

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

But I cannot get glossaries working. I know I need to run 'makeglossaries' or 'makeindex', but how could I do in aquamacs latex mode.

I tried `C-c index`

it shows

```
Running `Index' on `test2' with ``makeindex test2''
Couldn't find input index file test2 nor test2.idx.
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]
```

So how could make this glossaries package working?

And the version of software I am using is Aquamacs 3.3  GNU Emacs 25.1.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my version of Aquamacs, I use C-c glossaries, which appears to run makeglossaries.

My version information is Aquamacs 3.3  GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0, NS appkit-1344.72 Version 10.10.2 (Build 14C109)).